# How to make the menu collapsible in tablet mode (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, uinavigationbar

I have a menu that is collapsible in mobile mode but not in tablet mode, that is why the menu overlaps my logo which is unattractive. My menu is done using bootstrap and php. And the php code is retrieving the menu from word press. But i now remove the php codes and replaced it by viewing the source.

```css
.margin-20{margin-top: 20px;}
/*header*/
#header .head-social{background-color: #7DC651; width:100%; height: 37.48px;text-align:right;}
#header .head-social h3 {color: white;font-size: 13px;margin-top: 12px;font-family: 'Open Sans';text-align: right;display: inline-block; padding: 0 20px;}
#header .head-social .social-links {display: -webkit-inline-box;}
#header .head-social .social-links a{text-align:center;float: left;width: 24px;height: 24px;border: 2px solid white;border-radius: 100%;margin-right: 5px; /*space between*/align-items: flex-start;transition: all 0.4s;-webkit-transition: all 0.4s;background-color:white;color:#7DC651; display:flex;}
#header .head-social .social-links a i{align-self:center;color: #7DC651;transition: all 0.4s;-webkit-transition: all 0.4s;margin: 0 auto; font-size: 14px;}
#header .head-social .social-links a i::before{display:inline-block;text-decoration:none;}
#header .site-tele {text-align: right;}
#header .site-tele i{color: black;font-size: 25px;margin-right: 11px;}
#header .site-tele h3{font-family: 'Open Sans'; font-size: 15px;color: black;display: inline-block;}
#header #myNavbar .navbar-nav > li {display: inline-block;margin: 25px auto;}
#header #myNavbar .navbar-nav > li > a {padding-top: 0;padding-bottom: 0;line-height: 14px;color:#676767;float: left;border-right: 2px solid gray;}
#header #myNavbar .navbar-nav li:last-child a{border-right: none;}
#header .navbar.navbar-inverse {border-color: white;background-color: white;}
/*content*/

/*footer*/

/*responsiveness*/

@media screen and (max-width: 767px)
{
#header .head-social {height:86.48px;}
#header .site-logo a img {width: 200px;height: 50px;}
#header .navbar-header button{background-color: #7DC651;}
#header .site-nav nav .navbar-header .navbar-toggle {border-color: #7DC651; background-color: #7DC651;}
#header .navbar-header button span{color: white;}
#header .navbar-header .navbar-toggle:focus, .navbar-header .navbar-toggle:hover {background-color: #7DC651;}
#header .head-social .social-links {margin-right: 14px;}
#header #myNavbar .navbar-nav > li > a {border-right:none;padding-top: 15px;}
#header #myNavbar .navbar-nav > li {display: flex; margin: 0px auto;height: 40px;}
#header .navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse, .navbar-inverse .navbar-form {border-color: #7DC651;border-bottom-color: rgb(125, 198, 81);border-bottom: 1px solid #7DC651;margin-left: -104px;}
#header #myNavbar .navbar-nav > li:hover {background-color:#7DC651; }
}

@media screen (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) 
{

}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">

  <div id="header">
   <div class="head-social">
    <div class="container">
     <h3>3 Addres address address add, CT. 06002</h3>
     <div class="social-links">
         <a href="www.facebook.com" ><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href="www.twitter.com" ><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href="www.youtube.com" ><i class="fa fa-youtube fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href="www.instagram.com" ><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href="www.google.com" ><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="container margin-20">
    <div class="row">
     
     <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-3 site-logo">
       <a href="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/72/d3/dd/72d3dda7ff919e183c682467934010e4.jpg"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-9 col-md-7 site-nav">
       <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
           <div class="navbar-header">
             <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             </button>
           </div>
              <nav class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" role="navigation">
               <div id="myNavbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse"><ul id="menu-primarynav" class="nav navbar-nav"><li id="menu-item-37" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-22 current_page_item menu-item-37"><a href="http://localhost/bucarisbraces/">HOME</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-36" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-36"><a href="http://localhost/bucarisbraces/appointments/">APPOINTMENTS</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-35" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-35"><a href="http://localhost/bucarisbraces/driving-directions/">DRIVING DIRECTIONS</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-34" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-34"><a href="http://localhost/bucarisbraces/about-us/">ABOUT US</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-33" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-33"><a href="http://localhost/bucarisbraces/about-braces/">ABOUT BRACES</a></li>
</ul></div>        </nav>
       </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 site-tele">
       <i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       <h3>1-860-243-8989</h3>
      </div>
     </nav>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 </header><!-- #masthead -->
```

Comment: Consider reducing your code to a [mcve]. Focus on *"minimal"* and *"verifiable"*. Welcome to [so].

Comment: okay ill edit it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to collapse bootstrap nav from 991px, you can add some CSS to make what you needed. Here is an example of custom breakpoint for the bootstrap navbar. Hope it helps.

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .navbar-header {
      float: none;
  }
  .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
      float: none !important;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
      display: block;
  }
  .navbar-collapse {
      border-top: 1px solid transparent;
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top {
      top: 0;
      border-width: 0 0 1px;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
      display: none!important;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
      float: none!important;
      margin-top: 7.5px;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li {
      float: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .collapse.in{
      display:block !important;
  }
}
```